# Restyle all DatePickerTextBox within a WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl containing multiple DatePickers;

Currently, in order to restyle the pickers, I have to copy the same massive template four times:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
... Unrelated ResourceDictionaries...
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
      <DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" ...various properties...>
      <DatePicker.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}>
            <Setter Property="Template">

    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
        ... Ridiculous amount of XML...
               <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" ...more props...>
               <ContentControl.Template>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <TextBlock Text="Start Date"/>  <!-- This is the crucial change I want -->
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </ContentControl.Template>
               </ContentControl>
        ...Yet more XML...
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
            </Setter Property="Template">
         </Style>
      </DatePicker.Resources>
      </DatePicker>      

      <!-- Duplicate for end -->
      <DatePicker x:Name="EndDate" ...various properties...>
      <DatePicker.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}>
            <Setter Property="Template">

    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
        ... Ridiculous amount of XML...
               <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" ...more props...>
               <ContentControl.Template>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <TextBlock Text="End Date"/>  <!-- This is the crucial change I want -->
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </ContentControl.Template>
               </ContentControl>
        ...Yet more XML...
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
            </Setter Property="Template">
         </Style>
      </DatePicker.Resources>
      </DatePicker>      

      <!-- Duplicate for prev start -->
      <DatePicker ...>
          ... Same massive XML as above
      </DatePicker>

      <!-- Duplicate for prev end -->
      <DatePicker ...>
          ... Same massive XML as above
      </DatePicker>

   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have tried creating a `<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}></Style>` in UserControl.Resources to replace this, but I can't get it to be picked up.

Also, I can't find a way to bind the one piece of differing text to a parent property of DatePicker.

**Is there to restyle all 4 DatePicker textboxes with the same styling but with one (deeply nested) string changed?**

Answer (score 1):

You have your style under Datepicker.Resources. The styles are always picked up by resources of their parents, not their own resources.
Place that style somewhere else up in the hierarchy. For example, Grid.Resources.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I put it in one of the User control resource dictionaries, it fails to be picked up.